# Route incoming traffic through locally-established VPN

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, routing, iptables

I'm trying to setup a Debian 10 VM to serve as a VPN gateway. I want to use rules on my router (Ubiquiti Security Gateway) to direct certain devices (Apple TV, some IoT stuff) to through the VPN on the gateway.

The VPN gateway is setup as an OpenVPN client and I verify the VPN works with:

```
curl --interface tun0 ifconfig.co/json
```

My VPN gateway machine's static IP is `10.65.49.5`. If I set that as the default gateway on another system on that same network, IP forwarding works fine. I can see traffic flowing on the gateway using `iftop`. I've also found with bad `ip route` and `iptables` commands I can break the internet on the other client machine.

I've found some guides to doing exactly what I want, yet they seem to have no effect. This is the main thing I've tried:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -o tun0 -i ens3 -s 10.65.49.0/24 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -o tun0 -i ens3 -s 172.16.30.0/24 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT

iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -j MASQUERADE
```

Yet this seems to no effect. Using sites like http://ifconfig.co I can tell the VPN isn't being used.

So I must be missing something. I've also been playing around with `ip route` and have managed to break the internet but not much else.

Network info:

- Gateway VM IP is `10.65.49.5` on `ens3` and confirmed `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`
- My main LAN is `10.65.49.0/24`
- My VLANs live in `172.16.xx.0/24` blocks. Access from VLANs is probably another level of complication, but I'll settle for getting it to work on the main LAN network. My current tests are all being done within `10.65.49.0/24`

Comment: The logical place to put a VPN and to accomplish what you are talking about is on the security gateway. For what reason are you running the VPN on another system and trying to hairpin the traffic back from the security gateway? If you insist on this setup, then the most straightforward way is to change the default gateway on your network so all devices go through the VPN system and then setup rules on the VPN gateway to bypass certain devices and forward it on to the router. The VPN server should use the router as its default gateway.

Comment: One of the main reasons is performance. The Ubiquiti Security Gateway doesn't support hardware offloading for OpenVPN clients and thus you're limited to about 20 MBit of throughput with its rather sluggish CPU.